# How to insert multiple textbox values in databse those are checked with checkbox with php?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, textbox, insert

Below is an explanation of exactly what I want

On the submission form I have multiple checkboxs. when users click on checkbox a textbox appears next to it, where user input text. I want to insert the value of texbox in array and insert it in database with PHP-MYSQL.
 for example checkbox1 is index 0=>valueoftextbox, checkbox2 is index 1=>value of texbox2

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Serialize received $_POST.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="smth[]" value="One" />
<input type="checkbox" name="smth[]" value="Two" />
<input type="checkbox" name="smth[]" value="Three" />

<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
   $smth = serialize($_POST['smth']);
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$smth')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few pointer to get you going:

1) From PHP use:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

That way you can see WHAT is posted from your client-form.

2) Note that an unchecked checkbox ISN'T posted at all.

So if you have following checkbox in your form named "wantsnewsletter".

Then check that from PHP like this:

```
 if (isset($_POST["wantsnewsletter"])){
   // It was checked.
 } else {
   // It wasn't checked
 }
```

Futhermore you just have to think up some sensible naming and do the inserts into you DB.